# Android - ListView with ArrayAdapter and hidden TextViews

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with the ArrayAdapter in the ListView in my Android application. The TextViews that should be displayed have two possibilites, with an info text or without an info text. The problem appears while scrolling. When I scroll down and up again the TextViews that didn't had an info text now have a random info text (from one of the TextViews with info text). The problem appears because of the memory usage of the ListView. Now I am looking for a possibility to solve the problem. The result should show the TextViews (without the info text) after scrolling without the info text. So is there any good solution with using the ArrayAdapter in a ListView or is there any other Android widget to use?

Java Code (Activity class):

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(layout, null);

            holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout_textview);
            holder.infoText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_layout_infos);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        final OutputTweet outputTweet = tweetObjects.get(position);

        if (outputTweet.getText() != null) {
            holder.text.setText(outputTweet.getText());
        }

        if (!outputTweet.getInfoText().equals("")) {
            holder.infoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.infoText.setText(outputTweet.getInfoText());
        }


        return view;
    }
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/list_layout"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_layout_infos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/text_info_color"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_layout_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15sp"
     />

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for every solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an else clause to your last if clause that sets the view back to `View.GONE` or `View.INVISIBLE`. The view is being recycled, and since it was being shown before, it will still be visible when it is passed back to you.

In general when binding you need to bind ALL state, including visibility changes. Don't assume any state from the inflation because of the reuse of views.

Try this:

```
    if (outputTweet.getText() != null) {
        holder.text.setText(outputTweet.getText());
    } else {
        holder.text.setText("");
    }

    if (!outputTweet.getInfoText().equals("")) {
        holder.infoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.infoText.setText(outputTweet.getInfoText());
    } else {
        holder.infoText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Yes this works perfect. Thank you for the solution! :)